# Why doesn't e.preventDefault() stop my page from Refreshing?

Tags: javascript, submit, preventdefault

I just can't figure out, why my site is loading when pushing the submit-btn. Even though I tried to prevent this with e.preventDefault() in my function. Maybe someone can open my eyes.. I'm sitting next to this (small) problem since 2 Days.

```js
class Einkauf {
    constructor(produkt, anzahl){
        this.produkt = produkt;
        this.anzahl = anzahl;
    }
};

class UI {
    static showItems () {
        const items = [{
            Produkt: "Butter",
            Anzahl: 2
        },{
            Produkt: "Käse",
            Anzahl: 1
        }];

        items.forEach(item => UI.addItems(item));
    }

    static addItems (item) {
        const container = document.getElementById('grocery-list');
        const newItem = document.createElement('tr');
        newItem.innerHTML = 
        `<td>${item.Produkt}</td>
         <td>${item.Anzahl}</td>
         <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">x</a></td>`

         container.appendChild(newItem);
    }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.showItems());

//Neues Produkt einpflegen:
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Inputs definieren:
    const produkt = document.getElementById('produkt').value;
    const anzahl = document.getElementById('anzahl').value;

    const einkauf = new Einkauf(produkt, anzahl);
    
    UI.addItems(einkauf);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Einkaufsliste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-mLBxp+1RMvmQmXOjBzRjqqr0dP9VHU2tb3FK6VB0fJN/AOu7/y+CAeYeWJZ4b3ii" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center my-5 display-6">
            <span class="text-primary m-0">Einkaufs</span>
            liste
        </h1>
    

    <form id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="produkt">Was fehlt?</label>
            <input type="text" id="produkt" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="anzahl">Wie viel fehlt?</label>
            <input type="number" id="anzahl" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Hinzufügen" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> 
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
        <thead class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
            <td>Marke:</td>
            <td>Menge:</td>
            <td></td>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="grocery-list">

        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Maybe someone can figure the problem out and give me a short advice.

Best regards, Philipp.
```

Comment: Add the "onsubmit" listener to the *form*, not the button.

Comment: Btw, it doesn't matter here because the script is below all the HTML but you need `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.showItems);` instead. What you have will call the function when that line is hit, not later when the 'DOMContentLoaded' event happens.

Comment: So I move this line of code to the bottom, right? Thank you.

Comment: Your script is at the end of <body>, so it runs after all the elements already exist. Which means you don't need the event at all, you can just do `UI.showItems();`. Many years ago, scripts were always placed into the <head> of a document so you needed a way to make sure certain functions only run after the entire document is loaded. That's what listening for `'DOMContentLoaded'` was for. The crucial thing is to only pass the function itself as 2nd parameter to addEventListener, without the ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead be listening to the `submit` event on the form:

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const produkt = document.getElementById('produkt').value;
  const anzahl = document.getElementById('anzahl').value;

  const einkauf = new Einkauf(produkt, anzahl);

  UI.addItems(einkauf);
})

class Einkauf {
  constructor(produkt, anzahl) {
    this.produkt = produkt;
    this.anzahl = anzahl;
  }
};

class UI {
  static showItems() {
    const items = [{
      Produkt: "Butter",
      Anzahl: 2
    }, {
      Produkt: "Käse",
      Anzahl: 1
    }];

    items.forEach(item => UI.addItems(item));
  }

  static addItems(item) {
    const container = document.getElementById('grocery-list');
    const newItem = document.createElement('tr');
    newItem.innerHTML =
      `<td>${item.Produkt}</td>
         <td>${item.Anzahl}</td>
         <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">x</a></td>`

    container.appendChild(newItem);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.showItems());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Einkaufsliste</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-mLBxp+1RMvmQmXOjBzRjqqr0dP9VHU2tb3FK6VB0fJN/AOu7/y+CAeYeWJZ4b3ii" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <h1 class="text-center my-5 display-6">
      <span class="text-primary m-0">Einkaufs</span> liste
    </h1>


    <form id="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="produkt">Was fehlt?</label>
        <input type="text" id="produkt" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="anzahl">Wie viel fehlt?</label>
        <input type="number" id="anzahl" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Hinzufügen" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
      <thead class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
        <td>Marke:</td>
        <td>Menge:</td>
        <td></td>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="grocery-list">

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Maybe someone can figure the problem out and give me a short advice. Best regards, Philipp.
```

Comment: Thank you.. solved my problem within 2 min & made my day!